# Alternatives to getDeclaredMethods / getDeclaredFields / getConstructors

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface

I'm getting AVs when calling getDeclaredMethods / getDeclaredFields / getConstructors due to Reflection.getCallerClass being called in the above methods.

I've created a Java VM through JNI from a Delphi application. Unfortunately, I discovered that when calling certain methods in the java.lang.Class class, these methods call

```
checkMemberAccess(1, Reflection.getCallerClass(), true);
```

which causes an AV, since there is no real Java class on the stack, as I'm calling the getDeclaredXXX methods directly, and from JNI calls from Delphi.

In order to overcome getCallerClass, I created a Java class wrapper, like so:

```
public class DelphiClassHelper {

  private Field[] f;
  private Method[] m;
  private Constructor<?>[] c;
  private static DelphiClassHelper helper;

  public Field[] pGetDeclaredFields(ClassLoader cl, String ClassName) {
    Class<?> AClass = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Loading class: "+ClassName);
        System.out.println("ClassLoader: "+cl.toString());
        AClass = cl.loadClass(ClassName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    if (AClass!=null) {
        f = AClass.getDeclaredFields();
        return f;
    } else
        return new Field[]{};
  }

  public static Field[] GetDeclaredFields(ClassLoader cl, String ClassName) {
     helper = new DelphiClassHelper();
     return helper.pGetDeclaredFields(cl, ClassName);
  }

  public Method[] pGetDeclaredMethods(ClassLoader cl, String ClassName) {
    Class<?> AClass = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Loading class: "+ClassName);
        System.out.println("ClassLoader: "+cl.toString());
        AClass = cl.loadClass(ClassName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    if (AClass!=null) {
        m = AClass.getDeclaredMethods();
        return m;
    } else
        return new Method[]{};
  }

  public static Method[] GetDeclaredMethods(ClassLoader cl, String ClassName) {
     helper = new DelphiClassHelper();
     return helper.pGetDeclaredMethods(cl, ClassName);
  }

  public Constructor<?>[] pGetConstructors(ClassLoader cl, String ClassName) {
    Class<?> AClass = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("Loading class: "+ClassName);
        System.out.println("ClassLoader: "+cl.toString());
        AClass = cl.loadClass(ClassName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    if (AClass!=null) {
        c = AClass.getConstructors();
        return c;
    } else
        return new Constructor[]{};
  }

  public static Constructor<?>[] GetConstructors(ClassLoader cl, String ClassName) {
     helper = new DelphiClassHelper();
     return helper.pGetConstructors(cl, ClassName);
  }

}
```

My thought of creating the above is that the public static methods create a Java class, and then calls the instance methods pXXXX, which then calls one of the methods Class.getDeclaredMethods, getDeclaredFields, getConstructors, surely this will satisfy the getCallerClass call, hence, preventing the AV.

But no, I still get AVs. Is there any other framework that can provide the information that getDeclaredXXXX methods provide, or is there a way of working around the getCallerClass requirement, such as creating a fake class on the stack that can satisfy the Reflection.getCallerClass call?

Other parts of my Delphi to JNI application work, as long as it doesn't call any Java methods that eventually calls Reflection.getCallerClass.

Note, as I created the Java VM from a JNI call, there is no SecurityManager in place.

UPDATE: 24 Jan 2014
The cause of the AV is due to some optimization, which causes instances of objects to be placed in one of the CPU registers, which gets wiped when during calls to checkMemberAccess. Subsequently when the Delphi runtime attempts to retrieve the object from the CPU register and use it again, it causes AV, since the expected value was trashed.

Comment: Java is case sensitive should your method be called `getDeclaredMethods`? I don't think Java catches on when there's a case mismatch. Ditto for `getDeclaredFields` etc.

Comment: 1. The code compiles. 2. See 2nd last paragraph - "Other parts...work"

Comment: You're missing the point of the comment completely.

Comment: There are no case sensitivity issues here, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Did you try overriding all security policies to remove all access restrictions when you start the VM? `java.security.policy==myOverridePolicy.policy`  Also, did you check to see what `Reflection.getCallerClass()` returns when invoked from the native code?

Comment: Samhain, "there is no Security Manager in place".

Reflection.getCallerClass doesn't return, because it is the method that contains the code that throws the AV.

Comment: What version of VM?  I just ran a simple example of pure JNI creating a class instance and calling getDeclaredFields w/o issues in 1.6_30

Comment: What is an AV anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach appears correct. The question is what are you passing in regarding the ClassLoader c1 argument in your methods? This needs to be generated using a class from the same VM as the classes you are trying to introspect. Any class would do. If you have such a class, you can get the correct ClassLoader ny using that class in its constructor.